# Ubuntu [GRUB]doesn't show up in advanced boot options

Tags: boot, grub2

Installed Ubuntu successfully on a PC running Windows 7 but had no option in the boot menu.
This is after a failed installation where GRUB failed to install. I decided to reinstall  Ubuntu and got no error message about GRUB, but still don't see it in boot options.
Thanks

Comment: Need details or this may fix it.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

Access somehow your linux partition ex. LiveCD

A. Enter grub folder

```
/boot/grub
```

B. Edit grub file

```
sudo gedit menu.lst
```

C. Add

```
title    Ubuntu
root     (hd0,0)
kernel   /boot/vmlinuz-2...
initrd   /boot/initrd.img...
quiet
```

[In that case from (hd 0,0) means 1st disk 1st partition, conseqently (hd 1,0) would be 2nd disk, 1st partition and so on]

D. Save file and restart PC

OR

Use grub customizer with GUI

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Hope it would help :)

Comment: First suggestion applies to grub legacy. Almost all new systems are grub2. Grub Customizer is more for after you have installed and want to change things in grub. Better to run Boot-Repair.